# How to validate an email ID exists or not in spring mvc?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Can anyone please help me and suggest what to do

I am able to validate the email address pattern and send mail to that email address before that i want to check email address exists or not

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\.+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

Comment: Exists where? Be more clear.

Comment: `用户@例子.广告` is according to [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email) a valid email address. Do you want to exclude those? PS: I don't understand what you're asking either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a list with "existing" address, you need to send the mail and then verify that it reachs the destination.

If the mail server does not exist you will have an exception because the network connection can't be established. But if the account doesn't exist or is unavailable you won't have any error. After that you could test the "from" address to check if the mail has been rejected for some reason.

Comment: actually i am able to register with new users in the app and i am able to send mail to that particular email address ,their are chances that users can give wrong email address so i want know whether the emailId exists or not